# Google oauth getAccessToken() null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, google-api

I want to add google oauth to my web app, i already follow the google documentation about google oauth with php client library, but i got problem

Here my code

```
public function googleOauth() {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig(base_path('google_client.json'));
        //$client->setAccessType("offline");
        $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true); 
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Blogger::BLOGGER);
        $client->setRedirectUri(route('googleOauthCallback'));

        return redirect($client->createAuthUrl());
    }

    public function googleOauthCallback(Request $params) {
       if ($params->code) {
          $client = new Google_Client();
          $client->authenticate($params->code);

          dd($client->getAccessToken());
       }
```

But the `$client->getAccessToken()` return `null`

How to fix it ?

Comment: Try to dump the return value for the `authenticate()` method call. Based on the [source code for this library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php), you should see some more info.

Comment: array:2 [▼ "error" => "invalid_request" "error_description" => "Could not determine client ID from request." ]

Comment: Thanks, solved. I just repeat code on method googleOauth() to googleOauthCallback()